# How can I turn on the map mode for the scroll bar in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I wish to get an overview of my code next to the scroll bar in Visual Studio 2019, something similar to the VS Code's Minimap.

**How can I turn it on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open scroll bar options under Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars
and enable "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar"